# AWS EC2 instances - best suitable ec2 for a Laravel Project with cron jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I am currently developing an app that has cron jobs running in specified scheduled time(daily) and most of them are pulling data from amazon api, so I expecting a high cpu usage when this cron job runs. Also this instance host the server that are consumed by a frontend hosted in different ec2 instance. For now its under in development, so there is only one user testing the frontend.

I am using T3 medium with 30 Gig of storage. And my boss is not happy for the first billing - its USD113 on the first month.My question is, what ec2 instance you suggest for this kind of set up? I am new on aws, and I am wondering if this bill price is just right. Also,I create an AMI for the ec2 , is it billed also ?

And any suggestion on what are the more efficient way of set up for a Laravel project that hosts the api and running also multiple cron jobs?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't answer this for you; you need to benchmark and try different server sizes out. See what size meets your minimum requirements. If you're super cost sensitive, though, EC2 might not be the best option; something like Digital Ocean's $5/month instances might be better. (Side note: pulling data from the Amazon API probably won't be CPU intensive. Again, benchmark.)

Comment: AWS Lightsail is amazing value if you want to stay with AWS, otherwise Digital Ocean like CJ says may be a good option.  https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/ . AWS is pretty expensive, IMHO it's more aimed at enterprises who want to replace data centers or such and don't really care if the bill is 5 or 6 figures per month. Having said that I run a t2.nano that runs Wordpress, MySQL, PHP, and a few other utilities for about $5 per month to run 5 low volume websites.